# Slidy works in Safari but not in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pandoc

I am trying to run this simple example:

`pandoc -t slidy -s habits.txt -o habits.html`

Where `habits.txt` is shown below:

```
% Habits
% John Doe
% March 22, 2005

# In the morning

## Getting up

- Turn off alarm
- Get out of bed

## Breakfast

- Eat eggs
- Drink coffee

# In the evening

## Dinner

- Eat spaghetti
- Drink wine
```

This is on Mac OS X 10.10.5 with Safari 9.0.1 (10601.2.7.2), Chrome 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit), and Pandoc 1.15.2.

The resulting html file is rendered properly as slides with a counter, help and table of contents in Safari, but not in Chrome. In Chrome it's just a flat html with headers where there would be separate slide titles.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Here's the html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
  <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
  <meta name="author" content="John Doe" />
  <meta name="date" content="2005-03-22" />
  <title>Habits</title>
  <style type="text/css">code{white-space: pre;}</style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection, print"
    href="http://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy2/styles/slidy.css" />
  <script src="http://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy2/scripts/slidy.js"
    charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="slide titlepage">
  <h1 class="title">Habits</h1>
  <p class="author">
John Doe
  </p>
  <p class="date">March 22, 2005</p>
</div>
<div id="in-the-morning" class="titleslide slide section level1"><h1>In the morning</h1></div><div id="getting-up" class="slide section level2">
<h1>Getting up</h1>
<ul>
<li>Turn off alarm</li>
<li>Get out of bed</li>
</ul>
</div><div id="breakfast" class="slide section level2">
<h1>Breakfast</h1>
<ul>
<li>Eat eggs</li>
<li>Drink coffee</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="in-the-evening" class="titleslide slide section level1"><h1>In the evening</h1></div><div id="dinner" class="slide section level2">
<h1>Dinner</h1>
<ul>
<li>Eat spaghetti</li>
<li>Drink wine</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the resulting html?

Comment: Done. Thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 3):

Coworker figured it out: habits.html will be rendered properly in Chrome if hosted on a server and accessed through a regular URL, but not when it is read from the local disk. Here's the diagnostic:

> It is hitting this error in chrome on slidy.js ln 1275:
>
> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A
>   history state object with URL
>   'file:///Users/brettleibowitz/Desktop/slidy.html#(1)' cannot be
>   created in a document with origin 'null'.

Comment: jup, you can spawn a simple server with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Comment: Thank you for this tip! I just tried it, and it worked.